# Rules parameter description to appear in different lines

Tags: rules, 7

I want the description of a Rule to appear in two lines. In the description field I have tried '
' and '\n\r' but without any use.

```
  $items['my_custom_action'] = array(
    'label' => t('Some Label'),
    'triggers' => array('any'),
    'named parameter' => TRUE,
    'parameter' => array(
      'par1' => array(
        'type' => 'list<text>',
        'label' => t('Select an option'))),
        'options list' => array('1' => t('Option1'), '2' => t('Option2')),
        'description' => t('Line1') . '<br/>' . t('Line2'),
        'restriction' => 'input',
      ),
    ),
    'group' => t('My own group'),
  );
```

Please let me know how I can make the description appear in two lines.

It has to be simple. May be I am missing something basic :P

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 $descp = "line1 </br> line2";

 $items['my_custom_action'] = array(
    'label' => t('Some Label'),
    'triggers' => array('any'),
    'named parameter' => TRUE,
    'parameter' => array(
      'par1' => array(
        'type' => 'list<text>',
        'label' => t('Select an option'))),
        'options list' => array('1' => t('Option1'), '2' => t('Option2')),
        'description' => t($descp),
        'restriction' => 'input',
      ),
    ),
    'group' => t('My own group'),
  );
```